# Flex: Get self SWF file name?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, filenames

Is there a way I can programmatically determine the filename of the .swf my class is running in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Stage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html) has a [loaderInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) property, which contains a [url](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#url) property that has the information you're looking for. You can get the stage property from any DisplayObject in Flex.

trace(stage.loaderInfo.url);

Comment: Thanks.. Also I can use Application.application.stage.loaderInfo.url to get it from a NON DisplayObject, also it gives an Error if you try to access it before Application.CreationComplete.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like stage is ready until the FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE event is dispatched.

Answer (score 3):

Just a helpful note: If you load one SWF into another, the loaded (inner) SWF will return an erroneous result if you use `loaderInfo.url` to try to get the filename. For instance, something like:

`Path/To/Outer.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/1`

Instead of:

`Path/To/Inner.swf`

Beware!

That said, here is the code I use to get the current SWF name:

```
function SWFName(symbol:DisplayObject):String
{
    var swfName:String;
    swfName = symbol.loaderInfo.url;
    swfName = swfName.slice(swfName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); // Extract the filename from the url
    swfName = swfName.slice(0, -4); // Remove the ".swf" file extension
    swfName = new URLVariables("path=" + swfName).path; // this is a hack to decode URL-encoded values
    return swfName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not from within flash, afaik. What do you need it for? There might be a better way to do it.

Comment: Well I am building a custom Logger class, That will send the logs to a script to be saved. I am making it so I can reuse this class with other projects. So I want the class to be able to auto-detect what project it is running in, so it can log that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loaderInfo.loaderURL` to get the full path and name of you swf

Example of a class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite {
 private function init():void {
  removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, init);
  var myUrl:String=loaderInfo.loaderURL;
  var tmp:Array=myUrl.split("/");
  var myName:String=tmp[tmp.length-1].split(".swf")[0];
 }

 public function Main() {
  super();
  if (stage)
    init();
  else
    addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, init, false, 0, true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed a bit in more recent versions so I'll give an answer for Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 (geared towards Flash in browser, but you get the idea).

```
<s:Application ... applicationComplete="alertSwfUrl()">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

    private function alertSwfUrl():void {
        var a:LoaderInfo = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.loaderInfo;
        ExternalInterface.call('alert', a.url); 
    }

]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application
```

Check out the [LoaderInfo docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) to figure out how to use the `loaderInfo` object associated with the `stage`.